# Cannot find Google Awareness API

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-awareness

Following a guide from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/awareness), I have attempted to add the Awareness APIs as a dependency of my application using the following statement:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.6.1"
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Awareness API dependency has been renamed to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness`. Your compile statement should be as follows:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:9.6.1'
```

Comment: Thanks! how did you find this out ?

Comment: you can find google repository on "ANDROID_HOME/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms" this path. There you can see the packages. Now in official documentation also they have changed.